# how can u split the Photon?

Tags: visible-light, photons

**If any equations are there ,for split the light particle,  means
that i have a 1m length of light just consider that in that who can i 
split the light particle into 1/2 m length Pls tell**

Comment: By definition of the "photon", you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read a bit about light [on the web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light).

Physics has many levels/frameworks the main separation being between the quantum/particle framework and the continuous frameworks of classical physics.

In classical physics light is an electromagnetic wave  with a specific wavelength/frequency, and it obeys the special theory of relativity which has a fixed [velocity of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_of_light)  .

> The speed of light in vacuum, commonly denoted c, is a universal physical constant important in many areas of physics. Its value is exactly 299,792,458 metres per second.

This is an enormous velocity and the space it spans in a second of light seen is enormous. In classical physics the wavelength does not change except if the source is moving: the speed remains c but the wavelength changes to compensate. That is the way one studies in astronomy the [cosmic background radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMB) left over from the Big Bang, by the Doppler shift towards infrared of the original high energy light.

In classical light you could make wave packets of certain duration and therefore length, but not a meter long if you read again the speed of light numbers. In a nanosecond light goes three meters. A classical light wave that starts in a long [wave packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet), could be split in two with appropriate apparatus.

At this level we are in the interface between classical and quantum. In the microcosm, i.e. dimensions of Angstrom, light is an ensemble of photons, one of the [elementary particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) that are the building blocks of matter as we understand it now.

Photons have energy=h*nu where [h is a constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) and nu =c/lamda, nu,  is the frequency of light that will displayed in large dimensions when the photon is in an ensemble building up the electromagnetic light we see, lamda the corresponding wavelength. As a photon there is nothing that can be split in space the way you think of, there is no 1m length of photon. It is a point particle.